# RWD: Centering 2 divs vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I wanna center 2 `div`s vertically, I tired to use `vertical-align: middle` but that doesn't work, also tried the `margin`, doesn't work wither.

What can I do to center those two?

**CODE**

```css
.about{
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.aboutImg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; 
    left: 0px;
}
.textContainer {
    position: relative; 
    width: 60%; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

```html
<div class="about" id="aboutStrings">
  <img class="aboutImg" src="about1.jpg">
  <div class="textContainer">
    <h1>About Strings</h1>
    <p>Strings Ramen Shop pulls a piece of Japanese Culture to Chicago, we can be found in the heart of Chinatown, directly across from New Chinatown Square. While other restaurants may serve ramen along with a number of other entrees, Strings Ramen focuses specifically on ramen. Along with ramen, Strings will also offer the appetizing oden, a Japanese winter street food. On top of tasting delightful, the ramen at Strings is also affordable but gives the option of adding more deluxe ingredients. The menu includes four types of ramen broth with a variety of high-end ingredients that are added to make the dish even more delectable.
                One of the major aspects of Strings is the noodles themselves. Strings will make fresh noodles daily using only their unique dough mixer and noodle maker imported straight from Japan. The use of fresh noodles, and genuine broth combined with passion and the use of only the best ingredients will certainly set Strings Ramen Shop apart.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also want the image to resize according to the screen size, most importantly, the text should always be contained in the image. So if the height of the paragraph stretched to 500px when the screen gets smaller, the image height should automatically be resized to contain the text. I've included Bootstrap css.

Comment: Just making sure I'm understanding, you want the inner `<div>` to be vertically centered in the `.about` div?

Answer (score 0):

Without using Flexbox, you can use some absolute positioning to achieve this.

```
.about {
  position: relative;
}
.textContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

This would center the `textContainer` inside of the `about` container vertically.

CSS Tricks has a great resource for this [here](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/).

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align:middle` only applies to `inline-block` level elements

Try this in your css

```
.about{
  text-align: center;
}
.aboutImg {
  width: 40%; 
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.textContainer {
  width: 40%; 
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: you could also apply this to the `.about` div and center everything vertically within it

Comment: [Your wrong](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) It applies to inline-level and table-cell elements. It also applies to [::first-letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) and [::first-line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line).

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [vertical-align: middle;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) before using it.

When you use [vertical-align: middle;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) the parent element must have a height larger than it's content otherwise it will not center vertically.

**NOTE:** Values of 0 should not have units specified.

Here's a simple [weave](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#5cf749464fbfb49efb6dc54451eda620) that shows exactly how it's done.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: rgb(0, 28, 66);
  font: 20px arial;
}

header {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <h1>
     Hello
    </h1>
  </nav>
  <nav>
    <h1>
     world!
    </h1>
  </nav>
</header>
```